# Export to csv from muddatagrid in mudblazor c#

Tags: c#, csv, datagrid, mudblazor

I am using muddatagrid in mudblazar. I am taking a list from database table it has 20 columns but I am displaying only 7 columns in datagrid. I am doing export to csv for this datagrid table and I have the button above this datagrid table, Onclicking it the contents will be downloaded as csv file ,  when I click the button it takes all the 20 columns from the database table and adds in csv. I don't want 20 columns I want only the 7 columns (displayed in datagrid).To achieve this, I am trying to take the column names from datagrid and send it to server side and match the columns with database table and  download only that column as csv file. The problem is I don't know how to take the column names(displayed in muddatagrid) directly from datagrid.

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" Filterable="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive" Height="@((heigh-300).ToString() + "px")">
<Columns>
<Column T="RiskInventoryDTO" Field="RequestIDInfo" Title="Request ID" StickyLeft="true">
<CellTemplate>
<MudLink OnClick(()=>View(context.Item))"Typo="Typo.body2">@context.Item.RequestIDInfo</MudLink>
</CellTemplate>
</Column>
<Column T="RiskInventoryDTO" Field="ToolName" Title="Tool Name"  />
<Column T="RiskInventoryDTO" Field="RiskAssociated" Title="Risk Associated" />
<Column T="RiskInventoryDTO" Field="ApplicationCriticality" Title="App Criticality Score" />
<Column T="RiskInventoryDTO" Field="ITOwners" Title="IT Owners" />
<Column T="RiskInventoryDTO" Field="BusinessOwners" Title="Business Owners" />
<Column T="RiskInventoryDTO" Field="Requestcreatedby" Title="Request Raisedby" />
</Columns>
<NoRecordsContent>
<MudText>No matching records found</MudText>
</NoRecordsContent>
<PagerContent>
<MudDataGridPager T="RiskInventoryDTO"/>
</PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>
```

This is my datagrid with columns. I tried to find in-build function to take this columns but i coundn't find anything. Is there any in-build function to take that column names. Is there any other options to achieve this. I couldn't find example for this.

Thank you!!!